# How to add an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need the Librarian class to store books as they are created into an array... I just need help doing this and understanding how to do it. (I'm a beginner.) Also, part of the lab is to throw an exception and a try/catch. I've already inserted that. I hope it is right. Thank you.

```
  import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import book.Book;

public class Librarian
{
    private final static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final static PrintStream messagePane = new PrintStream(System.out);
    private final static PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);

    public void provideLibrarianServices() throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Book aBook = null;
        boolean provideLibrarianServices = true;

        do
        {
            output.println(
              "(C)reate, \n" +


              "(U)pdate, \n" +
              "(D)isplay, \n" +
              "(F)inish.");
            output.print("What would you like to do?: ");
            String response = keyboard.next();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            output.println();
            if ( response.trim().isEmpty() || response.trim().isEmpty() )
            {
                output.println("You did not enter anything. Please enter a valid response.");
                output.println();
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("C") )
            {
                if ( aBook == null )
                {
                    aBook = createBook();
                }
                else
                {
                    output.print("A book already exists. \n" +
                      "Creating a new one will delete the current book.\n" +
                      "Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ");
                    response = keyboard.next();
                    keyboard.nextLine();
                    output.println();
                    if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("Y") )
                    {
                        aBook = createBook();
                        if ( aBook == null )
                        {
                            output.println("Invalid information given - \n" +
                              "     A Book could not be created.\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            output.println("\nThe Book was created successfully.\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("U") )
            {
                if ( aBook != null )
                {
                    updateBook(aBook);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.println("You must create a book before you can update it!");
                    output.println();
                }
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("D") )
            {
                if ( aBook != null )
                {
                    displayBook(aBook);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.println("You must create a book before you can display it!");
                    output.println();
                }
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("F") )
            {
                provideLibrarianServices = false;
            }
            else
            {
                output.println("You did not enter a valid response. Please try again.");
                output.println();
            }
        }
        while ( provideLibrarianServices );
    }

    private Book createBook() throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch ( Exception anException )
        {
            messagePane.print("Sorry, could not create a book for the following reason:"
            + anException.getMessage());
        }


        String response;
        output.println("Please enter information about the book as requested\n");

        output.print("Title: ");
        String title = keyboard.nextLine();
        output.println();

        output.print("Author: ");
        String author = keyboard.nextLine();
        output.println();

        output.print("Copyright Date (Four digit year, no month or day): ");
        int copyrightDate = keyboard.nextInt();
        output.println();

        output.print("ISBN (10 or 13 characters): ");
        String ISBN = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        output.println();

        output.print("Primary Topic: ");
        String primaryTopic = keyboard.nextLine();
        output.println();

        double listPrice = 0;
        output.print("Do you know the list price? (Y/N): ");
        response = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        output.println();
        if ( response == null || response.trim().isEmpty() )
        {
        }
        else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("Y") )
        {
            output.print("List Price: ");
            listPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            output.println();
        }

        double acqPrice = 0;
        output.print("Do you know the aquisition price? (Y/N): ");
        response = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        output.println();
        if ( response == null || response.trim().isEmpty() )
        {
        }
        else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("Y") )
        {
            output.print("Acquisition Price: ");
            acqPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            output.println();
        }

        Book aBook = Book.create(
          title, author, copyrightDate,
          ISBN, primaryTopic,
          listPrice, acqPrice);

        output.println();
        output.println(aBook.toString());
        output.println();

        return aBook;

    }

    private void displayBook( Book aBook )
    {
        if ( aBook != null )
        {
            output.println();
            output.print(aBook.getTitle() + " By: " + aBook.getAuthor() + ", " +
              aBook.getCopyrightDate() + ", ISBN: " + aBook.getISBN() +
              "\n      " + aBook.getPrimaryTopic() + "|List Price: $" + aBook.getListPrice() +
              "|Acquisition Price: $" + aBook.getAcquisitionPrice() + "\n");
            output.println();
        }
        else
        {
            output.println("     !!! The supplied object handle was null !!!");
        }
    }

    private void updateBook( Book aBook )
    {
        String oldBook = aBook.toString();
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        do
        {
            output.println("Current book information: \n" + aBook);
            output.println();
            output.print(
              "(T)itle, \n" +
              "(Au)thor, \n" +
              "(C)opyright Date, \n" +
              "(P)rimary Topic, \n" +
              "(L)ist Price, \n" +
              "(A)quisition Price, \n" +
              "(F)inish. \n" +
              "What would you like to update?: ");
            String response = keyboard.next();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            output.println();
            if ( response == null || response.trim().isEmpty() )
            {
                output.println("You did not enter anything. Please enter a valid response.\n");
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("T") )
            {
                stillUpdating = updateTitle(aBook);
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("C") )
            {
                stillUpdating = updateCopyrightDate(aBook);
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("P") )
            {
                stillUpdating = updatePrimaryTopic(aBook);
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("L") )
            {
                stillUpdating = updateListPrice(aBook);
            }
            else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("F") )
            {
                stillUpdating = false;
            }
            else if ( response.trim().length() > 1 )
            {
                if ( response.trim().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("Au") )
                {
                    stillUpdating = updateAuthor(aBook);
                }
                else if ( response.trim().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("Aq") )
                {
                    stillUpdating = updateAcquisitionPrice(aBook);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.println("Invalid Response. Please try again.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output.println("Invalid Response. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        while ( stillUpdating );
        output.println("Original Book: \n" + oldBook);
        output.println();
        output.println("New Book: \n" + aBook);
        output.println();
    }

    private boolean updateTitle( Book aBook )
    {
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        int aSignal;
        String theSignal;
        String oldTitle = aBook.getTitle();
        output.println("Title: " + oldTitle);
        output.print("New Title: ");
        String title = keyboard.nextLine();
        aSignal = aBook.setTitle(title);
        theSignal = book.Book.getReturnSignal(aSignal);
        output.println(theSignal + "\n" + aBook);
        return stillUpdating;
    }

    private boolean updateCopyrightDate( Book aBook )
    {
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        int aSignal;
        String theSignal;
        int oldCopyrightDate = aBook.getCopyrightDate();
        output.println("Copyright Date: " + oldCopyrightDate);
        output.print("Copyright Date (Four digit year, no month or day): ");
        int copyrightDate = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        aSignal = aBook.setCopyrightDate(copyrightDate);
        theSignal = book.Book.getReturnSignal(aSignal);
        output.println(theSignal + "\n" + aBook);

        return stillUpdating;
    }

    private boolean updatePrimaryTopic( Book aBook )
    {
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        int aSignal;
        String theSignal;
        String oldPrimaryTopic = aBook.getPrimaryTopic();
        output.println("Primary Topic: " + oldPrimaryTopic);
        output.print("New Primary Topic: ");
        String primaryTopic = keyboard.nextLine();
        aSignal = aBook.setPrimaryTopic(primaryTopic);
        theSignal = book.Book.getReturnSignal(aSignal);
        output.println(theSignal + "\n" + aBook);

        return stillUpdating;
    }

    private boolean updateListPrice( Book aBook )
    {
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        int aSignal;
        String theSignal;
        double oldListPrice = aBook.getListPrice();
        output.println("List Price: " + oldListPrice);
        output.print("New List Price: ");
        double listPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        aSignal = aBook.setListPrice(listPrice);
        theSignal = book.Book.getReturnSignal(aSignal);
        output.println(theSignal + "\n" + aBook);

        return stillUpdating;
    }

    private boolean updateAuthor( Book aBook )
    {
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        int aSignal;
        String theSignal;
        String oldAuthor = aBook.getAuthor();
        output.println("Author: " + oldAuthor);
        output.print("New Author: ");
        String author = keyboard.nextLine();
        aSignal = aBook.setAuthor(author);
        theSignal = book.Book.getReturnSignal(aSignal);
        output.println(theSignal + "\n" + aBook);

        return stillUpdating;
    }

    private boolean updateAcquisitionPrice( Book aBook )
    {
        boolean stillUpdating = true;
        int aSignal;
        String theSignal;
        double oldAcquisitionPrice = aBook.getAcquisitionPrice();
        output.println("Acquisition Price: " + oldAcquisitionPrice);
        output.print("New Acquisition Price: ");
        double acqPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        aSignal = aBook.setAcquisitionPrice(acqPrice);
        theSignal = book.Book.getReturnSignal(aSignal);
        output.println(theSignal + "\n" + aBook);

        return stillUpdating;
    }


}
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Isolate a specific problem.

Comment: I just need to know how to create an array that... instantiation of the array(parameterless method, default array size is 4; no return type), insertion of a book object into the array(single parameter of Book type; no return type), and locating a book within the array(single parameter of String type; return type of Book)... I just don't know where to start or how to start it. does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much code there for me to go through it all but to keep a record of the created books you want to store them into a List, in this case an ArrayList is probably best.

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then to add a new book just do `books.add(book);`

To see how many are there do `books.size()`

etc.

Check out the list API documentation to see what you can do with it.

To implement the four methods - add them in your Librarian class. The signature of the method is described in the requirements, i.e. for the first one:
instantiation of the array(parameterless method, default array size is 4; no return type)

So method name instantiateArray, no input paramaters, no return type:

```
void instantiateArray() {
```

It says it creates a default array size of 4:

```
    array = new Book[4];
}
```

You need to declare the array as a field in Librarian:

```
Book[] array;
```

That's your method.

Break down the requirements for the other 3 methods the same way to create them. It sounds like the assignment wants you to use an Array rather than a List for some reason (even though a List would probably be better). Perhaps a later assignment will have you switch over to a List.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Also, I forgot to add that that that array needs to be a parameterless method; default array size 4; no return type... how would get around starting that?

Comment: Sorry, what you just said makes no sense....

Comment: i forgot to mention earlier and dont understand myself... I just need to know how to create an array that... instantiation of the array(parameterless method, default array size is 4; no return type), insertion of a book object into the array(single parameter of Book type; no return type), and locating a book within the array(single parameter of String type; return type of Book)... I just don't know where to start or how to start it. does this help?

Comment: I'm not going to do your assignment for you. It sounds like you are being asked to create methods to create an array in your object, do stuff with the array, find stuff, return stuff.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much! I didnt want you to do my assignment, but just help me figure out what I actually need to do because my proffessor hasnt answered me yet. Just one more question, for me to create this array method, would I have to delete or reconstruct the methods that I already have? The code that I have is a menu in a loop

Comment: See edit I just made.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so helpful! :)